# Deploying to iPad os 14.4 - 2nd device refused to deploy

Tags: ios, delphi, ipad, firemonkey

I'm using the free developer account from Apple

- can only deploy in Development mode.

I deployed to one iPad.  I've another device with exact 14.4
version, but on 2nd device it always hangs after the PAServer
calls the "iosinstall" executable...

it'll just show "Launching..." in Delphi for the longest time until it times out minutes later.
1st iPad deploys to device in about 1 minute.

Is there a way to find out what exact PAServer is stuck on?
(I already have verbose on)

Restarts do not seem to solve the problem.

The same 2nd device works great with XCode with the exact same provisioning.

Any ideas?

UPDATE on 9 Mar 2021 : I realised there is a Dec2020 Apple patch for 10.4.1. Patched up. Still does not work. Scenario : 3 pieces of iOS 14.4 devices (2 ipads and 1 iPhone). 1st piece (iPad) can install both Actual Project and Small Sample Project. 2nd piece (iPhone) can only install only Small Sample Project. 3rd piece (iPad) cannot install both Actual and Small Sample. It seems weird!

iOS all using 14.4
Using Delphi 10.4.1 with Dec'20 Apple patch

Comment: Update : realised there is a Dec2020 Apple patch for 10.4.1. Patched up. Still does not work.  Scenario : 3 pieces of iOS 14.4 devices (2 ipads and 1 iPhone).  1st piece can install both Actual Project and Small Sample Project.  2nd piece can only install only Small Sample Project.  3rd piece cannot install both Actual and Small Sample.  Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Using a different BundleIdentifier resolved the problem.